# как правильно закрыть диалоговое окно

Tags: c++, qt

Открываю диалоговое окно:

```
ManualSetting * dialog = new ManualSetting(threadbalancerautomode,0);
dialog->setModal(true);
dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
dialog->exec();
```

Закрываю окно:

```
QWidget::close();
```

Проблема иногда, довольно часто, в том, что окно не закрывается и приходиться повторно вызывать `QWidget::close()`. Хотя `QWidget::close()` возвращает true - нажимаешь на кнопку "Закрыть", а оно висит. Нажимаешь второй раз и окно закрывается:

```
#include "manualsetting.h"
#include "ui_manualsetting.h"

ManualSetting::ManualSetting(ThreadBalancerAutoMode *const threadbalancerautomode, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ManualSetting),
    threadbalancerautomode(threadbalancerautomode)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
}

ManualSetting::~ManualSetting()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ManualSetting::on_pushButton_8_released()
{
    QWidget::close();
}

#ifndef MENU_1_H
#define MENU_1_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <threadbalancerautomode.h>

namespace Ui {
    class menu_1;
}

class menu_1 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT  

public:
    explicit menu_1(ThreadBalancerAutoMode * const  threadbalancerautomode, 
 QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~menu_1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_pressed();

    void on_pushButton_4_pressed();

    void on_pushButton_6_pressed();

    void on_pushButton_3_pressed();

    void on_pushButton_5_pressed();

    void on_pushButton_2_pressed();

private:
    Ui::menu_1 *ui;
    ThreadBalancerAutoMode * const threadbalancerautomode;
};

#endif // MENU_1_H
```

открываю окно

```
#include "menu_1.h"
#include "ui_menu_1.h"
#include <graphwindow.h>
#include <manualsetting.h>

menu_1::menu_1(ThreadBalancerAutoMode *const threadbalancerautomode, QWidget 
*parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::menu_1),
    threadbalancerautomode(threadbalancerautomode)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
}

menu_1::~menu_1()
{
    delete ui;
}

void menu_1::on_pushButton_3_pressed()
{
    ManualSetting * dialog = new ManualSetting(threadbalancerautomode,0);
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog->exec();
}
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения ошибки

Comment: Из mainwindow --->     menu_1* dialog = new menu_1(threadbalancerautomode,0);
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog->exec(); Из menu_1 --->     ManualSetting * dialog = new ManualSetting(threadbalancerautomode,0);
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog->exec(); Закрываю QWidget::close(); И вот при переходе из manualsetting ---> menu_1 происходит не закрытие окна с первого раза. А только со второго.

Comment: `dialog->exec()` - блокирующий вызов. Где вы вызываете `close()`?

Comment: close() вызываю прямо в окне manualsetting. void ManualSetting::on_pushButton_8_released()
{
   QWidget::close();
}

Answer (score 3):

Для закрытия модиального диалога QDialog надо использовать функции
[QDialog::acept()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) - этот код возвращается, если пользователь нажал Ок в диалоге
[QDialog::reject()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#reject) - этот код возвращается, если пользователь нажал Cancel или закрыл диалог
[QDialog::done(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done) - это общий универсальный метод, где вы можете вернуть свой код возврата

```
void ManualSetting::on_pushButton_8_released()
{
    accept();
}
```

В вызывающем коде также возможно проверять с каким кодом завершился диалог

```
ManualSetting * dialog = new ManualSetting(threadbalancerautomode,0);
dialog->setModal(true);
dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

if (dialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    // Accept code
}
else
{
    // Reject code
}
```

Comment: Добавил void ManualSetting::on_pushButton_8_released()
{
    accept();
} Но все равно нужно два нажатия на клавишу on_pushButton_8

Comment: @zhilenkov, а у вас там точно одно окно создаётся?) или может у вас как-то не так сигнал с кнопки соединён..

Comment: А как это проверить? Может быть. Я не знаю.

Comment: @zhilenkov, когда откроется ваш диалог перетяните его мышкой, если под ним еще такой же диалог, значит что-то пошло не так

Comment: Пишу не для десктоп  а для промышленного пк.  У меня все окна на размер экрана.

Comment: @zhilenkov, тогда стать дебагером в конструктор диалога или добавить туда строку на вывод в консоль или что-то подобное, а какая ОС на целевом компе?

Comment: Собрал и поставил линукс.

Comment: Вот что заметил в отладчики  dialog->exec(); два раза вызывается.

Comment: @zhilenkov, тогда показывайте как слоты соединены с on_pushButton_3_pressed, возможно у вас там два раза connect() вызывается и кнопка отрабатывает дважды за одно нажатие

Comment: Я соединял, нажимал правой кнопкой мыши на кнопку и выбирал go to slot и pressed. А где посмотреть connect()?

Comment: @zhilenkov, в кьют-креаторе хз, создайте кнопку заново и соедините со слотом

Comment: Написал вот такой код     
    qDebug() << "ManualSettingOpen";

    ManualSetting * dialogManualSetting = new ManualSetting(threadbalancerautomode,0);
    dialogManualSetting->setModal(true);
    dialogManualSetting->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialogManualSetting->exec();

    qDebug() << "ManualSettingClose"; 
    Вот что выдала программа 
    ManualSettingOpen 
ManualSettingOpen 
ManualSettingClose 
ManualSettingClose 
ManualSettingOpen 
ManualSettingOpen 
ManualSettingClose 
ManualSettingClose 
ManualSettingOpen 
ManualSettingClose

Comment: Переделал pressed на clicked ошибка пропала. Надеюсь больше не вернется.